# Enabling deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a problem with the azure function. I'm trying to create a new deployment slot.
I have other functions deployed so when i try to do it this message appear :
Azure functions slots is currently disabled.
Enabling this feature will reset any pre-existing secrets. Function secrets can be found under the 'Manage' node for each function.
What will happend if this key will be reset?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, but this is not a programming question as required by SO's policies. Perhaps you should ask this on serverfault.com or similar sites.

Comment: Were you able to get an answer on this? Were there any issues when enabling slots?

Comment: I had the same question but couldn't easily find any answers... so I enabled slots and found that none of the Function Keys of the production slot app were reset or changed in any way . However neither App Keys or Function Keys they are automatically added to the app deployed to the new slot so they must be re-configured for each slot.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of keys:

**Host keys:** These keys are shared by all functions within the function app. When used as an API key, these allow access to any function within the function app.

**Function keys:** These keys apply only to the specific functions under which they are defined. When used as an API key, these only allow access to that function.

Each key is named for reference, and there is a default key (named "default") at the function and host level. Function keys take precedence over host keys. When two keys are defined with the same name, the function key is always used.

Each function app also has a special **master key**. This key is a host key named _master, which provides administrative access to the runtime APIs. This key cannot be revoked. When you set an authorization level of admin, requests must use the master key; any other key results in authorization failure.

For more information , follow the doc **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys**

Comment: Which of those keys/secrets will be removed/reset when enabling deployment slots?

Comment: I had the same question but couldn't easily find any answers... so I enabled slots and found that none of the Function Keys of the production slot app were reset or changed in any way . However neither App Keys or Function Keys they are automatically added to the app deployed to the new slot so they must be re-configured for each slot.

Answer (score 0):

It's described here [https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots.md

For me it added a new entry in the application settings:

```
{
    "name": "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType",
    "value": "Blob",
    "slotSetting": false
}
```

see for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobssecretstoragetype